# Is it possible to have the attributes fields already filled from the previous object?

Tags: qgis, editing, fields-attributes

I need to create a lot of points with lots of attributes, but most of the fields are the same, so I don't want to edit all the fields all the time. Is there a "remember previous fields" function available?
[image]

Comment: I know of ways to address this in ArcGIS (feature templates, some editing tricks), but not QGIS. The quickest way I know would be to only edit the attributes that are different as you create them, then when you're done open the attribute table, select records that will share a value, and Field Calculate all those records to have the same value for that field. It's a bit more work than having it filled out, but at least you only have to type the value once.

Answer (score 5):

In QGIS, try `Settings -> Options, Digitizing` tab:

```
Feature creation
[x] Reuse last entered attribute values.
```

This works for newly created objects, but not if you fill in data of already existing objects.

Answer (score 1):

Could you make use of the [Quick Multi Attribute Edit](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickMultiAttributeEdit/) plugin? You can create a number of points first, select a group of them, and bulk edit common attributes using the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are entering house number points please also try the 
house numbering qgis plugin:

https://github.com/marcobra/HouseNumbering