# QGIS adding features without attributes

Tags: qgis

i'm trying to add about 50 points in certain areas in QGIS and they all have the same exact value,  so i figured i can just have the placed without entering the data and then select them and add the value through a formula

i just have on issue that i have to confirm using "enter" after placing each point .. so is there any way to add a point with just a click without going through the attribute dialogue and pressing "Enter"?

Comment: I think this is a very similar question to this: [Is it possible to have the attributes fields already filled from the previous object?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141852/is-it-possible-to-have-the-attributes-fields-already-filled-from-the-previous-ob)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. 
Setting >> Options >> Digitalization
[image]

Comment: In English the option is: "Suppress attribute form pop-up after feature creation"